# Aceder à camada serviço a partir do controller

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-data, apache-solr

Olá,

Estou a desenvolver um web service REST que consulta dados do Apache Solr. Estou a usar Spring boot + data com repositórios Solr.
Não sei como interligar as camadas de serviço, respositório e o controller.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Controller**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Repositorio**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Service**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Uma classe que representação a configuração**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Logs**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como o controller consegue aceder hà camada de serviço ?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo fazer o seguinte:

O Controller acessar o Service e o Service acessa o Repository. Exemplo:

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class TesteController {

     @Autowired
     private TesteService testeService;

     public void fazAlgumaCoisa() {
         List<Teste> testes = testeService.fazAlgumaCoisa();
         // mais codigo
     }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class TesteService {

    @Autowired
    private TesteRepository testeRepository;

    public List<Teste> fazAlgumaCoisa() {
        testeRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TesteRepository extends JpaRepository<Teste, Long> {

}
```